# Prove If for all $A\subset X, f(A^c)=f(A)^c$ then $f$ is $1-1$ and onto.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was asked to prove that

> If for all $A\subset X, f(A^c)=f(A)^c$ then $f$ is $1-1$ and onto.

I successfully proved it using contradiction for both 1-1 and onto, however my professor said it would be better to prove it directly.

I have been unable to find a way to prove it directly so I was hoping someone could show me the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Proof:* Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Let $x,y\in X$ be two different points, and let $A_x= X\setminus \{x\}$, by hypothesis we have that $f(A_x)=Y\setminus f(\{x\})$. On the other hand it is easy to see that $y\in A_x$, and thus $f(y)\neq f(x)$, then $f$ is 1-1, to prove that $f$ is onto note that $Y\setminus f(X)= f(X^c)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and the proof is complete. $\square$